# I found an unknown UFW rule on my ubuntu server - have I been compromised?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, firewall

I posted this on information/security and someone said it might be better if I post this question here, so here I am.

The server is running the Kubuntu Desktop variant of Ubuntu (I transformed it into a server, I had things configured that would have been a pain to transfer to another installation.).

One day I decided to do a security check-up and I checked my UFW rules (`sudo ufw status`) and I found these rules that I don't remember adding:

```
49152                      ALLOW       Anywhere
49152 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Googling for "port 49152", etc does not bring up any useful information. I know that it is a private/dynamic/ephemeral port but I have no idea what the port was used for and why this firewall rule was on my server, and if possible are there any logs that I could check that would tell me what the port was used for and what added the firewall rule?

The process that was using the port seems to have died as running the following commands:

```
sudo netstat -tupln
sudo netstat -a
sudo lsof -i
```

show no signs of a process listening on the port.

List of installed packages: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XQRdqC6zXZ/

- Could I check what was previously using the port?
- Could this be something dangerous?
- Do you have something listening on port 49152 that you didn't configure?
- How could I find out what added the firewall rule?
- What types of logs should I look for and where would they be located?
- Have I been compromised?

Comment: Regardless of the answer.. you **really** want to apply a healthy chunk of privilege separation there - ideally not running development, desktop, cgi AND gaming roles off the same install. Keeping your system secure often involves trade-offs, and if you require that many features all at once you will be trading in security or sanity, or both.

Comment: @anx There is quite a lot of privilege separation and if possible services are running as nobody or their separate designated user. I also don't really do much gaming at all on this install. Is there anything else I should check for/improve?